# Does the Where Statement matter if the tables are joined?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if both queries will always return the same results. are they equal?

```
SELECT OT_ACC_NO , ACC_NO FROM ACCOUNTS
JOIN OTHER_TABLE ON OT_ACC_NO = ACC_NO
WHERE ACC_NO IS NOT NULL 

SELECT OT_ACC_NO , ACC_NO FROM ACCOUNTS
JOIN OTHER_TABLE ON OT_ACC_NO = ACC_NO
WHERE OT_ACC_NO IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Just `JOIN` equals `INNER JOIN` - ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2080416))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This where condition doesn't make any logical impact.

INNER JOIN ensures that records must exist in both tables and they cannot be NULL values.

Answer (score 5):

The two are equivalent.  Perhaps even more surprising is that the `WHERE` clause is unnecessary.  So, this is equivalent:

```
SELECT OT_ACC_NO, ACC_NO
FROM ACCOUNTS JOIN
     OTHER_TABLE
     ON OT_ACC_NO = ACC_NO;
```

Why?  Because an `INNER JOIN` returns rows only when the `ON` condition is *true*.  If either value is `NULL`, then the comparison returns `NULL`, which is treated as *false*.

I should note that although the final result will be the same, the execution plan for the queries may not be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Lets take a small step backwards and consider the equality operator and `NULL` values:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END FROM DUAL;
```

Now, surprisingly for some, this will return `Not Equal`.

If you consider `NULL` to stand for an unknown value then you are asking if an unknown value is equal to another unknown value and the answer is false.

For your query:

```
SELECT OT_ACC_NO,
       ACC_NO
FROM   ACCOUNTS
       JOIN OTHER_TABLE
       ON OT_ACC_NO = ACC_NO
```

This will join the tables when `OT_ACC_NO = ACC_NO` and, as we saw above, if either of those variables is `NULL` (unknown) then the result of the equality comparison will always be false and the rows will be excluded from the join result.

So, adding a where clause to test whether either `OT_ACC_NO` or `ACC_NO` are `NULL` will never exclude any rows as they will already have been excluded by the join condition.

Answer (score 0):

The question is marked with the `Oracle`, so the answers should be somehow carefull with topics a *no logical impact*, *equivalent* and *same result*.

Below sample data for case where the seconds query returns no data, but the first query fails with `ORA-01722: invalid number`

```
create table ACCOUNTS as
select '1-1'  ACC_NO from dual;


create table OTHER_TABLE as
select cast(null as number) OT_ACC_NO from dual;
```